# javascript, html form and array arithmetics

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I’m trying to make a simple script for a retailer with a webpage – we have three Fruits – `Apple` , `Banana`, `Orange`

Two Qualities each – Apple ( bad and good) , Banana( bad & good) and Orange (bad and good)... Bad in all cases an inferior quality.

So I have two quality options -- good and bad

Quantity  from 1 to 10

I did something like this with array but it is only applicable to two variable not three . Final result I want is –

I chose Apple > good > 5 units  =  5*4 = 20

Form Option - select (apple, banana, orange), select(good, bad) , select(number of units)

Here is what I have done

```
    costperfruit = new Array(4,5,6, 7,8,9);

    function setcost()
    {
        cpp = costperfruit[document.frm.colour_fruit.value*1-1];
        sum = cpp*document.frm.numberUnits.value;
        sum += "";
        pos = sum.indexOf(".");
        if (pos>0)
        {
            sum = sum.substring(0,pos+3);
            if (sum.indexOf(".")+3>sum.length)
                sum += "0";
        }
        else
            sum += ".00";

        document.frm.cost_per_fruit.value = cpp;
        document.frm.total_sum.value = sum;
    }
```

With this I can easily multiply number of units with cost of fruits. Green option is inferior quality in each case thus sells for 3,5,7 , One USD less than red, yellow, red orange

I want to see price when I choose --

orange> bad> 3 = 7*3 = 21
apple> bad > 4 units > 3*4 = 12

I'm using select form in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can work, but it is hard to maintain it. I recommend you to use some data structure to store product prices:

```
var prices = {
    "apple": {
        "good": 4,
        "bad": 5
    }
    "banana": {
        "good": 6,
        "bad": 7
    }
    "orange": {
        "good": 8,
        "bad": 9
    }
}
```

Then if you want to select price for specific item you simply use:

```
prices["apple"]["bad"]
```

Comment: Let me run it and try to fix in my solution with html tags. Will certainly let you know. I've have very little experience with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on suvroc's suggestion above, I added a bit of code to process the Object Literal.

Take a look at the following Fiddle and see if it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/f79vj0s3/

Note that I changed the Object:

```
// Object Literal
var produce = {
    "Apple": {
        "good": 
            {
            "qty" : 5, 
            "cost" : 2
          },
        "bad": 
            {
            "qty" : 3, 
            "cost" : 1
          }
    },
    "Banana": {
        "good": 
            {
            "qty" : 6, 
            "cost" : 3
          },
        "bad": 
            {
            "qty" : 4, 
            "cost" : 2
          }
    },
    "Orange": {
        "good": 
            {
            "qty" : 5, 
            "cost" : 3
          },
        "bad": 
            {
            "qty" : 3, 
            "cost" : 1
          }
    }
};
```